# in an act which, outside of the context of this article, I generally applaud

Tags: comprehension

Example: (news story ["Putin News: Will Vladimir Putin Declare Himself Tsar Of All The Russias?"](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/putin-news-will-vladimir-putin-declare-himself-tsar-all-russias-455097))

> What better way to bring back Russia’s imperial glory than to bring back its emperor? Russia, as you well know, was once an Empire—a real one, with an Emperor and all. **In an act which, outside of the context of this article, I generally applaud, the communists killed the entire imperial family in cold blood**, ending permanently the main line of the centuries-old Romanov dynasty (they have since become saints). There are still pretenders to the throne, of course, but none of them are terribly serious.

I don't understand what the author is trying to say. Why would he be applauding something horrible such as killing people?

Comment: That's something the author of the article woud have to explain, not a question about English...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as @Stephie says, this is not a question about language but about the author's motivation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author clearly says that

> ...outside of the context of this article, I generally applaud, the communists killed the entire Imperial family in cold blood,...

I think what he means is apart from the point of this article which glorifies the Imperial system as a whole, if he were to give an opinion on it, he'd say it was a good thing the communists kept the rising Imperial system in check.